# Calling a function from a header in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++-cli

I'm programming in Visual C++ 2010. I've got a example.h example.cpp and Form1.h.
Basically, I've pasted bits of code. I'm not able to include Form1.h in the example.h file, not sure why. But The main question is how do I call Test (which is in form1.h) from example.cpp? What would be the syntax? Is it possible to do this?

My Form1.h

```
#include "example.h" 
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    public: void Test(void)
    {
              // Does something
    }
}
```

My example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
#include "Form1.h"

Test();    // would like to call Test from here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. You *must* call functions from inside of another function. The code you currently have in your `example.cpp` file is invalid, because you are trying to call the `Test()` function at global scope.

   Make it look like this instead:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       Test();

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   This also solves the problem that you don't have a `main` function, which is the entry point to any C++ application.

   More generally, I would ***strongly*** recommend using one of the project templates that comes with Visual Studio to get started (rather than copying and pasting random bits of code, like you said). That ensures that you have all of the things you need to get started, like an entry point. Once you have a solid foundation, you can start building up from there.

   You might also find it useful to obtain either a book on C++/CLI or an online tutorial (such as this one: [Hello C++/CLI, Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8074/Hello-C-CLI-Part-1) and [Hello C++/CLI, Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8078/Hello-C-CLI-Part-2)).
2. Your `Test` function is a *member* function of the `Form1` class, which means that you need an object of that class in order to call it. Thus, the code should actually look like this:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       Form1^ frm = gcnew Form1();
       frm.Test();

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Alternatively, you could work around this by making the `Test()` function a `static` function. This would allow you to call it without having an instance of the class:

   ```
   public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
   {
       public: static void Test(void)
       {
           // Does something
       }
   }

   // ...

   int main()
   {
       Form1::Test();

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   However, beware that this means you cannot access any other *members* of the `Form1` class inside of the `Test()` function (because there is no `this` pointer).

   This should all be explained in whatever book/tutorial you decide to use to learn C++/CLI—search for a chapter about "Classes" or "Object-Oriented Design".